# Need to adjust heading and text description in HTML

Tags: html, css

Need to adjust heading and text description in HTML Layouts with description comes under the heading tag. Tried break line tag but unable to accomplish. Here is the code please help.
**Code:**

```
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Announcements</h3>
            <br>
            </p>Total positors y Privacy setting y Change every image y Template system_ y y Total number at
            registered
            users Last user registered </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>TIps</h3>
            </p>Total psitors y Scripto </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Tricks</h3>
            </p>Total psitors Testimonials </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Announcements</h3>
            </p>Total psitors y Privacy setting Main converns </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section-wrap{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #fff; flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .section-wrap > div{  flex-basis: 50%;}

  .imgBox { height: 30px; background: #eee;   display: flex; margin: 20px;
    align-items: center; justify-content: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the / from your opening <p> tags?  <p>Total positors y </p>

Comment: YES but does not seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

I changed your html, also used `flex-direction: column` for `.imgBox`, so description comes under the heading tag:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #fff;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.two-section {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.imgBox {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-div">
  <div class="two-section">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="img">
      <h3>Announcements</h3>
      <p>Total positors y Privacy setting y Change every image y Template system_ y y Total number at registered users Last user registered </p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="img">
      <h3>TIps</h3>
      <p>Total psitors y Scripto</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="two-section">
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="img">
      <h3>Tricks</h3>
      <p>Total psitors Testimonials </p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgBox"><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" alt="img">
      <h3>Announcements</h3>
      <p>Total psitors y Privacy setting Main converns </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you are using .section-wrap class in CSS file that does not exist in your HTML code.
> Use .section-div class instead and apply the following CSS in it.

```css
.section-div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #fff; flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .section-div > div{  flex-basis: 50%;}

  .imgBox { height: 30px; background: #eee;   margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Announcements</h3>
            </p>Total positors y Privacy setting y Change every image y Template system_ y y Total number at
            registered
            users Last user registered </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>TIps</h3>
            </p>Total psitors y Scripto </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Tricks</h3>
            </p>Total psitors Testimonials </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-div">
        <div class="imgBox"><img src="Images/favicon.png" alt="img">
            <h3>Announcements</h3>
            </p>Total psitors y Privacy setting Main converns </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```